# R Documentation in Virtual Studio Code Jupyter Notebooks formatting incorrectly

Tags: r, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

Whenever I try to find information of the documentation of a function in R, I see these strange symbols that mess up the formatting on titles in the documentation. I am using an R kernel for Jupyter Notebooks. This is what it looks like when I try to search up documentation for print using:
?print

[Improper Rendering of Titles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/krzlk.png)

I suspect it has something to do with the compiler, but I am not sure what is specifically wrong. Any solutions are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think this maybe a problem caused by the different formatting for escape sequences in R's traditional documentation and Jupyter Notebooks. They don't interpret these escape sequences in the same way.

As for the solutions, maybe you can try to use RStudio for the documentation or use a different help command. You could try to use help(print, help_type="html").

Hope these solutions can help you solve the problem.